# Is green thread the implementation of m:1 thread model?

Tags: multithreading, scheduling

[Green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) are threads that are scheduled by a virtual machine instead of natively by the underlying operating system.

It does sound like it actually meets the [m:1 thread model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#N:1_.28User-level_threading.29), in which m user-level threads correspond to 1 kernel-level entity.

Tell me the difference between those two terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "green threads" usually refers to the case where scheduling is performed by a virtual machine, whereas the M:1 thread model can be implemented using any user-space threading library (e.g. [GNU Pth](http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/)).

Most VMs implementing green threads today schedule some number of user-level threads using a single OS thread, thus preventing programs from taking advantage of multiple cores. In principle, a VM **could** use multiple OS threads (Erlang uses this technique to allow its [lightweight processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#Concurrency_and_distribution_orientation) to take advantage of SMP); such a VM would no longer fit the "M:1 thread model".

Comment: About virtual machine, I guess it is not the same thing as "virtual processor", which is actually a kernel process?

Comment: No - "virtual machine" in this context means a user-mode process that executes bytecode, such as (older versions of) Java and Ruby.